# Nested dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I have a long list of status codes by month, sth like:

```
stats = pd.DataFrame(
    [
         ['2016-01', 200, 'xxx.com'],
         ['2016-01', 400, 'xxx.com'],
         ['2016-01', 200, 'xxx.com'],
         ['2016-02', 200, 'xxx.com']
    ],
    columns=['day', 'status_code', 'url']
)
```

I want to finally plot a few line charts with one line for each status code. I already found out that this table holds the correct information:

```
pivot = stats.pivot_table(index=['day', 'status_code'], aggfunc=len)
```

Looks like:

```
                        url
month   status_code     
2016-01 200            2
        400            1
2016-02 200            1
```

or as image:

[image: as image]

So it's somewhat the information I need.

However:

1.) I already fail at accessing that information. What's e.g. the syntax for getting the number of urls with status code 200 for 2016-01?

2.) How would i plot that? I want to draw multiple lines where x-axis is the month and the y-axis is the status-code-count.

3.) Why is the outer right column named 'url' anyway? I didn't include the url in my pivot table.

Comment: 1 problem per question, this is too broad. 1. `pivot.loc[('2016-02',200)].sum()` pass a tuple to access the multi-index and call `sum`. 2. you'd have to either convert the index to a datetime and access the month using `.month` or strip the month out and plot. 3. you called `pivot_table` with an `aggfunc` and it did this on the remaining columns so it reuses the column names not sure why this is a mystery to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `crosstab()`:

```
stats = pd.DataFrame(
    [
         ['2016-01', 200, 'xxx.com'],
         ['2016-01', 400, 'xxx.com'],
         ['2016-01', 200, 'xxx.com'],
         ['2016-02', 200, 'xxx.com']
    ],
    columns=['day', 'status_code', 'url']
)

df = pd.crosstab(stats.day, stats.status_code)

df.plot()
```

Comment: That's super awesome. It looks like that crosstab is doing essentally the same as `pivot = stats.pivot_table(index='month', columns='status_code', values='url', aggfunc=len)`